# Up and Down arrow keys stop working after dismissing a popup dialog with keyboard

Tags: bug, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, popups

- Start typing a post
- Bring up a pop-up dialog via a toolbar button (e.g. "Hyperlink")
- Type/copypaste whatever you want and dismiss it with `<Enter>`
- => In the textarea contol, Up and Down arrow keys now stop working
- -> If I dismiss the dialog by pressing a button in it with mouse, this doesn't happen

A workaround is to `<Shift>-<Tab>` out of the control and `<Tab>` back.

Firefox 59.0.2 x64 win7.

Comment: No repro with Chrome

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Edge. Probably a Firefox bug.